# Write a cached page before it is reclaimed

Tags: linux, caching, memory-management, kernel

everyone. I am stuck on the following question.

I am working on a hybrid storage system which uses an ssd as a cache layer for hard disk. To this end, the data read from the hard disk should be written to the ssd to boost the subsequent reads of this data. Since Linux caches data read from disk in the page cache, the writing of data to the ssd can be delayed; however, the pages caching the data may be freed, and accessing the freed pages is not recommended. Here is the question: I have "struct page" pointers pointing to the pages to be written to the ssd. Is there any way to determine whether the page represented by the pointer is valid or not (by valid I mean the cached page can be safely written to the ssd? What will happen if a freed page is accessed via the pointer? Is the data of the freed page the same as that before freeing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cleancache module? You should only get valid pages from it and it should remain valid until your callback function finished.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a cleancache/frontswap reimplementation? (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/cleancache.txt).

The benefit of existing cleancache code is that it calls your code only just before it frees a page, so before the page resides in RAM, and when there is no space left in RAM for it the kernel calls your code to back it up in tmem (transient memory).

Searching I also found an existing project that seems to do exactly this: http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/:

> Bcache is a Linux kernel block layer cache. It allows one or more fast
>   disk drives such as flash-based solid state drives (SSDs) to act as a
>   cache for one or more slower hard disk drives.
>
> Bcache patches for the Linux kernel allow one to use SSDs to cache
>   other block devices. It's analogous to L2Arc for ZFS, but Bcache also
>   does writeback caching (besides just write through caching), and it's
>   filesystem agnostic. It's designed to be switched on with a minimum of
>   effort, and to work well without configuration on any setup. By
>   default it won't cache sequential IO, just the random reads and writes
>   that SSDs excel at. It's meant to be suitable for desktops, servers,
>   high end storage arrays, and perhaps even embedded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Indeed my implementation is based on flashcache, which serves the similar purpose to Bcache. Following is a more specific expression of my question:

Comment: For the writing of each clean page, there is a corresponding BIO structure. However, I want to delay the submission of BIO by pending it in a queue. My questions are: 1) Can the page be modified and thus becomes dirty when BIO is in the queue? 2) Does the writeback only write the modified portion of page to the disk, or the whole page? 3) If the page is clean during its being in the queue, is the page able to be freed? @lsk

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve looks like the following:

- Before the page is evicted from the pagecache, you want to cache it. This, in concept, is called a Victim cache. You can look for papers around this.
- What you need is a way to "pin" the pages targeted for eviction for the duration of the IO. Post IO, you can free the pagecache page.
- But, this will delay the eviction, which is possibly needed during memory pressure to create more un-cached pages.
- So, one possible solution is to start your caching algorithm a bit before the pagecache eviction starts.
- A second possible solution is to set aside a bunch of free pages and exchange the page being evicted form the page cache with a page from the free pool, and cache the evicted page in the background. But, you need to now synchronize with file block deletes, etc